# How to run 2 sql queries in php to different table to make dropdown lists in html form?

Tags: php, html, sql, forms

Trying to make a user input form in html where the user select input is based on drop down lists. The first drop down list is made in php from an sql query to one table and the second drop down list is made in the same php file but with a different sql query to another table in the same database. I can get 1 to work but not 2 - the drop down lists show the correct number of items returned but they are blank.

I have tried searching solutions and can get the form to work using php arrays without the sql queries. The sql queries return the correct list when run in myphpadmin and I have also tried to get the results in an array but with no success. I am using mariadb for the sql database. I can run 2 queries in the same php file to make 2 tables to show the results but cannot figure out how to get the results into working drop down lists in html

[php file with 2 sql queries to different sql table as different html tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhVYA.jpg)

```
<!-- add new item to the database-->
<?php
// set variables for the php to read from the HTML below
$inputA = "";
$inputB ="";

$errorMessage = "";
$successMessage = "";

// check data transmitted using post method
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $inputA = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['inputA']);
    $inputB = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['inputB']);
    
    // data validation
    do {
        // check if all fields are completed as required
        if  ( empty($inputA) || empty($inputB)) {
            $errorMessage = "All fields are all required";
            break;
        } 
        
        //SQL query to update database
        $sql = "INSERT INTO trial (inputA, inputB) " .
                "VALUES ('$inputA', '$inputB')";
        //run query
        $result = $connection->query($sql);

        //if db connection query NG then show error
        if (!$result) {
            $errorMessage = "Invalid query" .$connection->error;
            break;
        }

        //reset variables ready for next use
        $inputA = "";
        $inputB ="";

        //show success message
        $successMessage ="Breakdown added";
        
        //redirect back to table page
        header("location: index.php");
        exit;

    } while (false);
}
?>

<!-- HTML set up-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html land="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Add New Item</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<!-- main body of page -->
<body>
    <!-- title -->
    <div class="container my-5">
        <h2>New Item</h2>

        <!-- show message under title on error -->
        <?php
        if ( !empty($errorMessage) ){
            echo"
            <div class='alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show' role='alert'>
                <strong>$errorMessage</strong>
                <button type='button' class='btn-close' data-bs-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'></button>
            </div>
            ";
        }
        ?>
        
        <!-- HTML form to collect data-->
        <form method="post">
  
            <!-- input based on drop down list from database -->
            <div class="row mb-3">
                <label class ="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Input A</label>
                <div class ="col-sm-6">
                    <select name = "inputA" class = "form-control">
                    <option value = "" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">inputA select</option> <!--to add blank at loading-->
                    <?php
                    // include the database connection file
                        include_once("config.php");
                    //get info for drop down lists on html form from the database
                        $sql = "SELECT fruit FROM fruit";
                        $mc_list = $connection->query($sql); // run query and store as variable
                        //use while loop to fetch data from database and make into category array
                        while ($category1 = mysqli_fetch_array($inputA,MYSQLI_ASSOC)):; //variable with SQL result stored in
                    ?>
                        <option value ="<?php echo $category1["inputA"]; ?>">
                            <?php echo $category1["inputA"]; ?> <!--to show the category content to the user-->
                        </option>
                    <?php
                        endwhile;
                        //while loop must be terminated

                    ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- input based on drop down list from database -->
            <div class="row mb-3">
                <label class ="col-sm-3 col-form-label">inputB</label>
                <div class ="col-sm-6">
                    <select name = "responding_mbr" class = "form-control">
                    <option value = "" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">inputB select</option> <!--to add blank at loading-->
                    <?php
                    // include the database connection file
                        //$mysqli->next_result();
                        $sql1 = "SELECT veggies FROM veggies";
                        $inputB = $connection->query($sql1); // run query and store as variable
                        //use while loop to fetch data from database and make into category array
                        while ($category2 = mysqli_fetch_array($inputB,MYSQLI_ASSOC)):; //variable with SQL result stored in
                    ?>
                        <option value ="<?php echo $category2["inputB"]; ?>">
                            <?php echo $category2["inputB"]; ?> <!--to show the category content to the user-->
                        </option>
                    <?php
                        endwhile;
                        //while loop must be terminated
                    ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!--show succss message-->
            <?php
            if (!empty($successMessage) ) {
                echo "
                <div class='row mb-3'>
                    <div class='offset-sm-3 col-sm-6'>
                        <div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show' role='alert'>
                            <strong>$successMessage</strong>
                            <button type='button' class='btn-close' data-bs-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                ";
            }
            ?>

            <!-- boot strap control buttons -->
            <div class="row mb-3">
                <div class="offset-sm-3 col-sm-3 d-grid">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
                <div class="colsm-3 col-sm-3 d-grid">
                    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="index.php" role="button">Cancel</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

<?php
    //close connection
    mysqli_close($connection);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check the web server error log. Sure you field name is veggies not veg?

Comment: All the sql table is fer to veggies (just using this as an example to prove the code but I can't get it to work. Confirmed table name is "veggies" and column name is "veggies". Query works when getting the data as a table but not when I try to make a drop down list. I have been trying to query it and add it to an array but that is also showing an array of the current number of items but they are blank! - e.g. when run I get: Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] =>) when I would expect it to be Array ( [0] => carrots[1] => cabbage[2] => turnip). Struggling to figure out why

Comment: I don't see any attempt here to put the data into dropdown lists, unless I'm missing something? All you've shown is how you put it into HTML tables. The process should be extremely similar really, except that you echo slightly different HTML strings containing the data. Can we have a [mre] of the issue please? You can [edit] your question to update it.

Comment: Apologies, you are absolutely correct and I have posted the wrong code with the question (I posted the code to make the table to prove connection is working before I asked the question), now corrected with code to make the drop down tables which is returning blank drop down lists

Comment: What **exactly** is not working with the given code? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Also, be warned that your `INSERT`  query is highly vulnerable for SQL injection. Have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several errors in your code here. Let's first fix the code for the second dropdown, called `veggies`. You have to use the column name as the index.

```
<div class="row mb-3">
    <label class ="col-sm-3 col-form-label">inputB</label>
    <div class ="col-sm-6">
        <select name = "responding_mbr" class = "form-control">
        <option value = "" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">inputB select</option> <!--to add blank at loading-->
        <?php
        // include the database connection file
            //$mysqli->next_result();
            $sql1 = "SELECT veggies FROM veggies";
            $inputB = $connection->query($sql1); // run query and store as variable
            //use while loop to fetch data from database and make into category array
            while ($category2 = mysqli_fetch_array($inputB,MYSQLI_ASSOC)):; //variable with SQL result stored in
        ?>
            <option value ="<?php echo $category2["veggies"]; ?>"> // <------ use the column name here as index, as you're using MYSQLI_ASSOC
                <?php echo $category2["veggies"]; ?> // <------ use the column name here as index, as you're using MYSQLI_ASSOC
            </option>
        <?php
            endwhile;
            //while loop must be terminated
        ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now for your first dropdown, you are using the wrong variable for the result. `inputA` should be `mc_list` and again you have to use the column name as index.

```
<div class="row mb-3">
    <label class ="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Input A</label>
    <div class ="col-sm-6">
        <select name = "inputA" class = "form-control">
        <option value = "" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">inputA select</option> <!--to add blank at loading-->
        <?php
        // include the database connection file
            include_once("config.php");
        //get info for drop down lists on html form from the database
            $sql = "SELECT fruit FROM fruit";
            $mc_list = $connection->query($sql); // run query and store as variable
            //use while loop to fetch data from database and make into category array
            while ($category1 = mysqli_fetch_array($mc_list,MYSQLI_ASSOC)):; // use mc_list here, instead of inputA
        ?>
            <option value ="<?php echo $category1["fruit"]; ?>"> // <------ use the column name here as index, as you're using MYSQLI_ASSOC
                <?php echo $category1["fruit"]; ?> // <------ use the column name here as index, as you're using MYSQLI_ASSOC
            </option>
        <?php
            endwhile;
            //while loop must be terminated

        ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Raphael, that solved the issue, main item was I wasn't using the column name as index - changed and all is good. Also many thanks to the other comments / advice, I will look into them also.